# Call powershell scripts with AX 2009

Tags: powershell, batch-file, axapta, x++

How can I proceed to run a powershell script from AX ? is it possible to do this through batch job? I mean is it allowed by AX to do that on server side process ?I had a lot of problems to run some processes like FTP upload, file generation etc.
Thanks for help
regards,
Thomas

Comment: What have you tried? Isn't PowerShell designed for such administration? See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272856.aspx. 2009 might be a different story...

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code and it works:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process  process;
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
;
process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.set_FileName("powershell.exe");
startInfo.set_Arguments("path_to_my_powershell_script");

startInfo.set_UseShellExecute(false);
startInfo.set_RedirectStandardError(true);
process.set_StartInfo(startInfo);
process.Start();
```